# javascript - turning camera photo into a string of url

Tags: javascript, android, android-camera, ocr

I am working on an ocr function for my javascript android application. Most of the ocr available online requires a valid url to retrieve the image and from there, it scans for characters. I tried using tesseract.js.

But the function we will like to do is to get the image from the phone either by the camera or gallery itself using its native camera and scan for characters from the picture used.

I was told that in java there is a function and i was wondering if there is any for javascript.

Hope you can help me out with this, thank you! Feel free to ask me for any more information needed.

I followed this link: http://progur.com/2016/10/how-to-use-tesseract-for-ocr-javascript.html

And i copied everything as needed.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @NigamPatro Hi, i have added the link in.